# Measure of closeness to one of two points

Tags: classification, descriptive-statistics, measurement

There is a finite set $W$ with two distinguished points $A$ and $B$. There are two measures of closeness of a given $X\in W$ to $A$ and $B$, respectively, denoted by $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$.

In particular, $\rho_A(X)=0$ if and only if $X=A$ and $\rho_B(X)=0$ if and only if $X=B$.

My aim is

1) To find some (statistical) measure to see if a given $X\in W$ is closer to $A$ or to $B$.

2) (If possible) If this measure uses the whole dataset $\{(\rho_A(X),\rho_B(X)): X\in W\}$ then to find its approximation which uses for example only $\{(\rho_A(X),\rho_B(X)): \rho_B(X)\le d\}$ for a small $d$.
The reason is that it is (computationally) easy to find $X\in W$ such that $\rho_B(X)=d$ for given $d$.

MY TRY

A linear regression of $\rho_A(X)$ on $\rho_B(X)$ for all $X\in W$. Then the given $X$ is closer to $A$ or $B$ if $(\rho_A(X),\rho_B(X))$ is in one of the corresponding half-planes.

Any ideas are highly appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $(1)$? After all, your preceding definitions immediately answer it: $X\in W$ is closer to $A$ when $\rho_A(X)\lt \rho_B(X)$.  What, then, is intended by the word "statistical"? Indeed, what is statistical about this question?  Presumably you conceive of *measuring* or *sampling* something, but what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber Thanks. $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are not comparable.
You are right, the word "statistical" is not applicable here.

Comment: Please explain in what sense those measures are "not comparable."  You imply they both have non-negative real values and you characterize both as "closeness," so how could they *not* be comparable?

Comment: @whuber As they can be in different "units of measurement".

Comment: @whuber Imagine $W$ be a population and $\rho_A (X)$ equal the height of the highest person minus the height of $X$, $\rho_B (X)$ equal the weight of the heaviest person minus the weight of $X$. The we need to know if a given person is more tall than heavy or not.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete: in your use of the word "closer" you imply comparability.  It looks like whatever problem you actually face has gotten lost in the abstractions.  Could you tell us what that problem is?

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I have to admit that my question is not perfectly stated. I think the example with height and weight is representative.

Comment: But what are you asking?  How to make two different quantities commensurable?  If that's so, it isn't a matter for statistics to decide that.

Comment: @whuber I think a matter for statistics is to choose a representative sample of $W$ to use my idea with linear regression. Anyway you are 100% right, my question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

Possible idea (full normalization):

Compute all values of $\rho_A$ on the dataset, sort them, and associate to $X$ the rank $r_A(X)$ of $\rho_A(X)$ in this array. $r_A(X)$ is an increasing function of $\rho_A(X)$ and is uniformly distributed. Defined $r_B$ the same way, then compare $r_A$ and $r_B$.

Not necessarily better than your idea. Takes non linearity into account but ignores the dependence between the two distances.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that $\rho_A$ may not be uniformly distributed.

Comment: It needs not be. $r_A$ is the uniformly distributed version of $\rho_A$. The idea is to replace something that is not uniformly distributed by something that is. Also this removes problems of $\rho_A$ not being in the same unit as $\rho_B$: $r_A$ and $r_B$ have the same unit.